# jumping inside loop

Tags: c

C language allows jumping inside loop.  What would be the use of doing so?

```
  if(n > 3) {

    i = 2;
    goto inner;
  }

   /* a lot of code */

   for(i = 0; i < limit ;i ++) {

    inner:
    /* ... */
   }
```

Comment: The use of doing such a thing is to greatly annoy CS profs around the world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device

> In computer science, Duff's device is an optimized  implementation of a serial copy that uses a technique widely applied in assembly language for loop unwinding.

...

> **Reason it works**
>   
> The ability to legally jump into the middle of a loop in C.

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly a questionable construct.  A design that depends on this behavior is probably a poor design.

You've tagged this as C++, but C++ (intelligently, IMO) *doesn't* allow you to jump inside a loop where a variable was declared in the first part of the for statement:

```
int main()
{
    int q = 5;

    goto inner;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        q *= 2;
inner:
        q++;
        std::cout << q << std::endl;
    }    
}
```

g++ output:

```
l.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
l.cpp:12: error: jump to label ‘inner’
l.cpp:7: error:   from here
l.cpp:9: error:   crosses initialization of ‘int i’
```

Initializing `i` *before* the loop allows the program to compile fine (as would be expected).

Oddly, compiling this with `gcc -std=c99` (and using `printf` instead) *doesn't* give an error, and on my computer, the output is:

```
6
13
27
55
```

as would be expected if `i` were initialized *outside* the loop.  This might lead one to believe that `int i = 0` might be simply "pulled out" of the loop initializer during compilation, but `i` is still out of scope if tried to use outside of the loop.

Comment: I find out that i value is garbage!

Comment: @Nyan: That might imply that this is either undefined behavior (which I would expect to be caught in `-Wall`) or that it's a bug in gcc.  I'm using GCC 4.2.1...  Comeau online in strict C99 gives two warnings about skipping initialization of `i`.  So, I'm not sure what the correct behavior is.  Probably need to consult the standard.

Comment: @Mark Rushakoff: C99 allows jumping into the scope of the declaration - however doing so leaves the declared variable uninitialised.  Reading an uninitialised variable is just as bad as it always was.

Comment: @caf: Which section of the standard says that?  Maybe I'm just overlooking it, but I didn't find it in my copy of the C99 draft.

Comment: @Mark Rushakoff: 6.8.6.1 puts the only restriction on the `goto` statement being that you can't jump into the scope of VLAs ("identifier having variably-modified type").  6.8 says that initializers are evaluated and values are stored in the objects "each time the declaration is reached in the order of execution, as if it were a statement".  So if you jump past an initializer, it is never "reached in the order of execution" and the variable is left with an indeterminate value.

Answer (score 2):

If you've ever coded in Assembler (ASM), then you'll know that GOTOs are pretty standard, and required, actually. The C Language was designed to be very close to ASM without actually being ASM. As such, I imagine that "GOTO" was kept for this reason.

Though, I'll admit that GOTOs are generally a "bad idea, mmmkay?" in terms of program flow control in C and any other higher level language.

Comment: GOTOs fit into a general category that I call "Rules that you should ONLY break after you understand why it's a rule in the first place."

Comment: I agree with you completely. That said, I have yet to find a case in C or any other high level language where I needed to use GOTO. The only time I ever recall using GOTO was in ASM and BASIC (and the latter was over 25 years ago.)  :-)

Comment: @Pretzel I'm new to C, but as far as I can tell it seems standard to 1) define an error checking macro with a `goto` to an `error` label, 2) use this macro in every function, 3) use an `error` label in every function to clean up and free memory. What do you use in place of `goto` for error checking and cleaning up?